# Free Windows software to crop and resize pictures

Tags: windows, images, image-processing

I have to cover the following use cases. At the moment i use "Paint", "Paint3d" or "Fotos" in combination but i want one app that covers them (easy to use not much more):

- set a standard aspect ratio (16:9, 4:3 ...)
- set an custom aspect ratio
- setting height or width by pixel

for all i want be able to re-position the frame where to crop or if frame is larger than image i want to fill with color or transparency.

Comment: Did you have a look at e.g. Gimp, Irfanview?

Comment: I'll think gimp could cover it, but my hope is, there is an really small app not covering much more than i need (don't need to really edit the image).

Comment: Voted up for Paint.NET, if you learn the hotkeys you can do it in 3 secs.

Comment: if you would create answers i would accept them :-) - thanks so far

Comment: I deleted my comment because I had mentioned Fotografix which was malware that I figured out later.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at  XnviewMP. 
The frame tool permits to define a  colored frame around image (but no transparency). The crop tool  permits to select a portion of image. 
Standard aspect ratios, custom aspect ratios and setting height or width are available in both tools